# Error of value <br of type java.lang.String cannot converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, mysql, string, json

I'm having problem with string cannot convert to JSONObject.Anyone could help to solve this problem? Thanks and very appreciate for helping.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","test","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $response = array();
    $fullname=$_POST["fullname"];
    $result = mysql_query("select fullname,contact, DATE_FORMAT(reserveDate,'%e-%c-%Y') reserveDate, 
            DATE_FORMAT(reserveTime,'%h:%i %p') reserveTime,
            pax,tableNumber
            from reserve inner join customer using (customerID)
            where fullname=$fullname" );    
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {  
        $response["reserve"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            // temp user array

            $reserv = array();

            $reserv["fullname"] = $row["fullname"];
            $reserv["contact"] = $row["contact"];
            $reserv["reserveDate"] = $row["reserveDate"];
            $reserv["reserveTime"] = $row["reserveTime"];
            $reserv["pax"] = $row["pax"];
            $reserv["tableNumber"] = $row["tableNumber"];
            // push single product into final response array

            array_push($response["reserv"], $reserv);

        }

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;
        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No user found";
        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

JSONPARSER class

```
package com.example.easy;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        //json = sb.toString();
        json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
        System.out.println("jsonstring ="+json);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

There is an error occur in ReserveInfo class. Get this error" value  .

```
package com.example.easy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Custname extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView custinfo2,lblempty2;


        Button btnsearch1;
        TextView custinfo,lblempty;
        ScrollView svcustdetails, svreserve;

        AutoCompleteTextView txtcustname ;
        String Contacts[];
        int arraysize;  
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONParser jParser2 = new JSONParser();
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_RESERV = "reserv";
        private static final String TAG_FULLNAME = "fullname";
        private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contact";
        private static final String TAG_DATE = "reserveDate";
        private static final String TAG_TIME = "reserveTime";
        private static final String TAG_PAX = "pax";
        private static final String TAG_TABLE = "tableNumber";
        JSONArray reserv = null;
        JSONArray reserv2 = null;
        JSONObject json2;
        String contactno;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custname);

        btnsearch1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);

        svcustdetails=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.svcustdetails);
        svreserve=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.svreserve);
        custinfo2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custinfo2);

        txtcustname = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcustname);     

         txtcustname = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcustname);

            btnsearch1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsearch1);
            lblempty2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblempty2);

        new LoadContact().execute();

        btnsearch1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                if(txtcustname.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Custname.this,"Please enter customer name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    reset();
                    new ReserveInfo().execute();
                }   
            }
        });
    }

    class LoadContact extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();    
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.2.2/Laicamproject/checkName.php", "GET", params);            
            // Check log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Name: ", json.toString());
            Contacts=new String[arraysize];

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    reserv = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESERV);
                    arraysize=reserv.length();
                    Contacts=new String[arraysize];
                    for(int a=0;a<arraysize;a++){
                         JSONObject c = reserv.getJSONObject(a);
                        Contacts[a]=c.getString(TAG_FULLNAME);
                    }   
                } else {
                    System.out.println("no user found");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("e3"+e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            //ArrayList with duplicates String
            List<String> dupList = (List<String>) Arrays.asList(Contacts);

            //Converting ArrayList to HashSet to remove duplicates
            LinkedHashSet<String> listToSet = new LinkedHashSet<String>(dupList);

            //Creating Arraylist without duplicate values
            List<String> contlist = new ArrayList<String>(listToSet);

            System.out.println("Customer list: " + contlist );

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Custname.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,contlist  );
            // Set the adapter 
            txtcustname.setAdapter(adapter);
            txtcustname.setThreshold(1);    
        }

    }

    class ReserveInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();       
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Custname.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading reservation");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String n=txtcustname.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_FULLNAME,n ));
            json2 = jParser2.makeHttpRequest("http://10.0.2.2/Laicamproject/cName.php","POST", params);
            System.out.println("params"+params);
            try {
                reserv2 = json2.getJSONArray(TAG_RESERV);
                System.out.println("Reservation"+reserv2.toString());
                int i=0;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("e1=="+e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            int num=1;
            JSONObject c2;
            try {
                int success = json2.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    for(int i=0;i<reserv2.length();i++){
                        c2 = reserv2.getJSONObject(i);
                        //System.out.println("c2.getString(TAG_CONTACT).==="+c2.getString(TAG_CONTACT));
                        //System.out.println("c2.getString(TAG_FULLNAME).==="+c2.getString(TAG_FULLNAME));  
                        custinfo2.setText("Name \t: "+ c2.getString(TAG_FULLNAME)
                                +"\nPhone \t: " + c2.getString(TAG_CONTACT));   

                        lblempty2.append("\n["+num+"] "+"Date \t\t: "+ c2.getString(TAG_DATE)
                                    +"\n\t Time \t\t: " + c2.getString(TAG_TIME)
                                    +"\n\t Pax \t\t\t: "+ c2.getString(TAG_PAX)
                                    +"\n\t Table \t\t: "+ c2.getString(TAG_TABLE)+"\n");
                    }
                }else{
                    showAlert();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("e2=="+e.toString());
        }
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }

    public void showAlert(){
        Custname.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Custname.this);
                builder.setTitle("No contact number found")
                       .setCancelable(false)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                               txtcustname.setText("");
                               reset();
                           }
                       });                     
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();               
            }
        });
    }

    public void reset(){
        lblempty2.setText("");
        custinfo2.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look to your php and, to me, seems that the root is a `JSONArray` and not a `JSONObject`. Your `makeHttpRequest` should return a `JSONArray` instead of a `JSONObject`

Also String comparison in Java is performed through the `equals` method, == check the `String`'s reference.

For instance

```
if(method == "POST")
```

and `if-else` branch also

Comment: May I know where is the comparison of String tat I did wrongly?

Comment: But im just wonder that i also have another class which search by contact number is working well in this exist code but just the problem with search by name.

Comment: I mean i has 2 ways to search for customer information. One is search by contact number, another is search by customer name. I can run well in contact number class but just cannot run in this Custname class. Thats why im thinking is it the problem is my php.

Comment: can you post what the php is returning ? The JSON you get from your php

Comment: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot converted to JSONObject
I try to print out the the String json from JSONParser but php just return <br />

Comment: that's the error. I would like to see what you are try to convert from string to json

Comment: actually what can I do in php so that it can return the information to JSONObject?